# PHPUnit: how test the __() php

Tags: php, phpunit

I have this exception:

```
throw  new \DomainException(__("message d'erreur"));
```

I don't know how can I do the test of this instruction by PHPUnit: **__()**.

Comment: Do you mean the `_` function? I.e. the alias for `gettext`?

Comment: `'message d'erreur'` is faulty, use `'message d\'erreur'` instead

Comment: Yes, it's the php function to translate the text.

Comment: `$this->assertTrue(function_exists('__'), '__() function missing');` if you rely on it, else mock it.

Comment: I want to mock it. How?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test about it…?

Comment: I have this instruction in my method, I want to mock it.

Answer (score 0):

Im sure there are other ways which i'm not aware of but I would do it like the following, if you downvote please comment why. If I learn something new I'm happy.

---

Ok, depending on whether the application expects the function to be defined to work or whether its expected but not part of the current test you could mock it:

Using: `php-mock/php-mock-phpunit`

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class SomeTest extends TestCase
{
    use \phpmock\phpunit\PHPMock;

    /**
     * __() function must exist or test fails.
     */
    public function testDoubleUndescoreFunction()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(function_exists('__'), '__() function does not exist');
    }

    // or

    /**
     * __() function will be mocked.
     */
    public function testDoubleUndescoreFunction()
    {
        // mock __() function
        if (!function_exists('__')) {
            $mocks['__'] = $this->getFunctionMock(__NAMESPACE__, "__");
            $mocks['__']->expects($this->any())->willReturnCallback(
                function ($value) {
                    $this->assertInternalType('string', $value);
                    return $value;
                }
            );
        }

        // test
        $this->assertTrue(function_exists('__'), '__() function does not exist');    

        try {
            //
            // run test which will cause the exception

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->assertInstanceOf('DomainException', $e);
            $this->assertEquals('message d\'erreur', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
?>
```